# RegEx capture specific string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Hi everyone, I have a problem. I'm trying to use regex to get all lines that are not end with

_0.jpg
_s.jpg
_m.jpg
_l.jpg

Example Lines:

9Uikt/ifehr54mg__0.jpg
9Uikt/idg4hdmg2_s.jpg
9Uikt/igdffgggfmg4_m.jpg
9Uikt/img3teg3gegg7_l.jpg
**9Uikt/imgerhw45h70.jpg**
**9Uikt/imggq4ge37s.jpg**
**9Uikt/img3f37m.jpg**
**9Uikt/img34g3f7l.jpg**
**9Uikt/imgf3f34t4t73l_.jpg**
**9Uikt/imgf3f34t4t73l_2.jpg**

The bold ones I am trying to get.

Between 9Uikit/ and .jpg any character can happen, except the characters that are not allowed for file names

"*:<>?/\|

I have tried this code

`.*(_(?![0-9][a-zA-Z])).*\.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!.*_[0sml]\.jpg$).+\.jpg$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tnyQYj/3)

**Details**

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?!.*_[0sml]\.jpg$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[0sml]` - a `0`, `s`, `m`, `l` char
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `jpg` - `jpg` string
  - `$` - end of string anchor
- `.+\.jpg$` - any one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, `.jpg` string and end of string.

Or, `.*(?<!_[0sml])\.jpg$` if you can afford a lookbehind:

```
.*(?<!_[0sml])\.jpg$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BeEIca/3). Details:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?<!_[0sml])` - no `_` and `0`, `s`, `m` or `l` char immediately on the left is allowed
  -`\.jpg$` - `.jpg` at the end of string.

Comment: OP doesn't want to match them ie `^.*(?<!_[0-9a-zA-Z])\.jpg$` or `^.*(?<!_\w)\.jpg$`

Comment: This one works except on something like _2.jpg or _a.jpg

Comment: @Vanisa What do you mean? That these are valid strings and should be matched?

Comment: I updated my first post. I dont want to get the lines that are ending with _0.jpg
_s.jpg
_m.jpg
_l.jpg but it happens that i need a line that ends with _1.jpg or _h.jpg. I hope you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Vanisa Then precise the character class pattern, `.*(?<!_[0sml])\.jpg$`

Comment: .*(?<!_[0sml])\.jpg$ works thank you for your work!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is perhaps a little light on what other combinations you might want to reject. From what I can see you don't want to match '7_' in which case the negative lookahead is the thing to do

A Perl regex might look like

```
    if(m/img(?!7_).*jpg/) {print}
```

Note that SED and AWK don't support negative lookahead, but you did not say how you were executing the regex

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this regex, which I think is simpler to read and understand.

```
\w+\/?.*?_\w\.jpg
```

```js
const testCases = [
  "9Uikt/img7_0.jpg",
  "9Uikt/img7_s.jpg",
  "9Uikt/img7_m.jpg",
  "9Uikt/img7_l.jpg",
  "9Uikt/img70.jpg",
  "9Uikt/img7s.jpg",
  "9Uikt/img7m.jpg",
  "9Uikt/img7l.jpg",
  "9Uikt/img7l_.jpg"
];

const re = /\w+\/?.*?_\w\.jpg/gi;

testCases.forEach(tc => {
  if (tc.match(re)) {
    console.log("Matched: " + tc);
  } else {
    console.log("Not matched: " + tc);
  }
});
```

Comment: This would accept something like `img7__.jpg` (2 underscores). For the sake of simplicity, it would be an acceptable alternative. Some anchors are missing. Otherwise, something like `img7_7.jpg.something else` would also match.